# My Azure pipeline does not load what so ever. I'm not sure what to do

Tags: azure

When I open up azure and create an image classification pipeline, the pipeline is loading indefinitely.[image]

Although I have seen many Azure loading screen issues, they are stuck on either pending, or pipeline history.

I have tried restarting and upgrading my subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I open up azure and create an image classification pipeline, the pipeline is loading indefinitely.

It may cause due to the network connectivity issues, i tried from my end in my machine with good network connectivity it works well as shown below.

[image]

For more information or any issues while using pipeline refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/known-issues/azure-machine-learning-known-issues?view=azureml-api-2) and further issues on network you can post your question [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/).